# Unable to set greeting text for Messenger bots

Tags: node.js, facebook, messenger

I'm trying to set a greeting text for one of my [Messenger](https://www.messenger.com/) bot [like this](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-facebook-chat-bot-node-heroku/):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"Greeting"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

As well as [like this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text/):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{
    "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Also, the same is set from my page's **messaging settings**

[image: messaging settings]

Messenger correctly shows the Get Started button:

[image: Messenger correctly shows the Get Started button]

But nothing like greeting comes on the bot

[image: nothing like greeting comes on the bot]

What could be the problem apart from [page access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45596366/2404470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you need exactly. However, let me guess that you want to something which once someone clicks the Get Started button, then the messenger bot send the user like "Welcome to the Bot! I wanna help you with xxx", right?

First, you need to set the Get Started button postback.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "get_started": {"payload": "<postback_payload>"}
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Besides talking to the server using curl, you need to handle The Get Started Button Postback with writing the code in your file app.js.

```
switch (payload) {
    case 'get_started':
        sendGetStarted(senderID);
        break;

    default:
        sendTextMessage(senderID, "Postback called");
}
```

For further more information, please check the documentation on https://messenger.fb.com/developers/tutorials/setting-up-the-welcome-screen/

Comment: Although you're late to the party. I probably need this only. Jazakallah!